# How to check reverse condition with contains in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, select, sql-server-2005

I am using contains in my select statement to filter street addresses from table as shown below

```
DECLARE @ADDRESS VARCHAR(100) = '0 RUBIN CT APT C2'

SET @ADDRESS = '"' + @ADDRESS + '*"'

SELECT * FROM tbl_StreetRecords
WHERE ZipCode = '02021'
AND contains(CompleteAddress,@ADDRESS)
```

In my database I have street address 'RUBIN CT APT', not '0 RUBIN CT APT C2'. I want to retrieve data that matches the address 'RUBIN CT APT'.

I can't use LIKE operator because I have 50 million records.

Comment: I'm not getting it, why not just `Contains(CompleteAddress, 'RUBIN CT APT')`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `CONTAINS` with a `LIKE` subquery for matching only a start:

```
DECLARE @ADDRESS VARCHAR(100) = 'RUBIN CT APT'

SELECT * 
FROM (
SELECT * FROM tbl_StreetRecords
WHERE ZipCode = '02021'
AND contains(CompleteAddress,@ADDRESS)
) AS S1 
WHERE S1.CompleteAddress LIKE 'RUBIN CT APT%'
```

This way, the `LIKE` operator query will be run against a smaller set of records
*(Contains will use Full-text indexes to get all rows where `Completeaddress` contains `RUBIN CT APT` and the `Like` operator filters the result to get rows where `Completeaddress` column start with this value)*

Comment: First Check how contains works in SQL server. Your query will not return any record.

Comment: @Dineshalla Why it will not return?

Comment: Contains will use Full text indexes to get all rows where Completeaddress contains `RUBIN CT APT` and the Like operator filters the result to get rows where Completeaddress column start with this value

Comment: From Front end i am getting address as "0 RUBIN CT APT C2" not "RUBIN CT APT", Change it in your query and verify once.

Answer (score -2):

```
DECLARE @ADDRESS VARCHAR(100) = '0 RUBIN CT APT C2'

 SET @ADDRESS = '"' + @ADDRESS + '*"'

SELECT * FROM tbl_StreetRecords
WHERE ZipCode = '02021'
AND CHARINDEX(AddressLine1, @ADDRESS) > 0
```

Comment: If you suggesting an alternative solution, you should state it explicitly and also explain why an alternative solution is needed here